# OctoberCMS Eager Loading with and where condition

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I would like to filter my query with where condition. Let's say I have a Product model, this has a relationship with the Buyer model. I want to get the list of Product model bought from a group of Buyers where the Buyer is 65yo and above.

```
$query = Product::with('Buyer')
  ->where('Buyer.age','>=',65)
  ->get();
```

However, I couldn't place the where condition like this, it shows "Unknown column for Buyer.age". Please advise how can I filter my result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
$query = Product::with('Buyer')
   ->whereHas('Buyer', function($q){  // whereHas will only return products whose buyer is >= 65
       $q->where('age','>=',65);
   })
  ->get();
```

Comment: thank you. but this will return all the product list, where I only need the product list with 65 yo buyers.

Comment: @mgggg I have updated my answer. Please check and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it:

```php
$query = Product::whereHas('Buyer', function ($query) {
   $query->where('age', '>=', 65);
})->with(['Buyer' => function($q){
   $q->where('age','>=',65);
}])
  ->get();
```